# How can I update only part of the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is the State object:

```
const initialState = {
  data: {
    user: '',
    token: '',
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
case 'DO_SOMETHING':
return {...state, data: action.payload }
```

If I soft copy the state as shown above, I will overwrite the entire `data` part of the state. How can I update only the user with the given payload without overwriting the `token`?

Comment: What are the properties of `action.payload`?  If it only has a `user` property, you could try `return {...state, data: {...state.data, ...action.payload}}`.  If it has both properties, you need to pull them off individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, (considering action.payload is the entire data object)

```
case 'DO_SOMETHING':
return {...state, data: { ...state.data, user: action.payload.user } }
```

Answer (score 4):

If the payload is just the `user`, then simply use the same destructuring pattern you used for the `state` object in general:

```
return {
  ...state,
  data: {
    ...state.data,
    user: action.payload
  }
}
```

This pattern can be nested as much as you like, so you can have large structured state objects and just pass around the fields you want in the payloads.

Answer (score 2):

Spread the nested object too:

```
return {...state, data: {...state.data, user: action.payload} }
```